# icons not visible clearly in internet explorer, resolution gets redused

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, icons, png

i am new web developer and designer, I used some icons.png for dropdown button, it is visible clearly in Firefox and Chrome but IE not supports.

it shows like this in IE:

[image]

but actual image is: ( Firefox and chrome displays fine)

[image]

Used html code  for image:

```
<img id="arrow_up" src="images/up_arrow.png" height="16" width="16"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer will not support for less or higher image size from original size. if we resize image from `html` or `css` then the image quality will get reduced from **IE**, so we have to display original image size as it is, then only the resolution issue will get solve.

```
<img id="arrow_up" src="images/up_arrow.png"/> // now image size is 20x20
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can share your work (URL or JSFiddle) it will be possible to let you know exactly what the problem might be.

Both look pix-elated to me, it might be that your actual image is smaller than 16px x 16px which will result in this. IE usually handles these worse and might be why you are getting this result.

Try make your image 16px x 16px or larger and see if this solves the problem.